# Create object from class stored in variable

Tags: java

I have a public abstract class `Animal` with subclasses `Dog`, `Cat`, `Mouse`. I am parametrizing tests and I'd like to use the type as a parameter. I am following [this](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/junit/junit_parameterized_test.htm). Is there a way to store the type in a variable? For example my test might be:

```
@Test
public void test_cat() {Cat(name='Tom');}

@Test
public void test_mouse() {Mouse(name='Jerry');}

@Test
public void test_dog() {Dog(name='Spike');}
```

I'd like to parametrize this so that the concrete type is in a variable and then instantiated `Object concreateType = Cat.class; concreteType(name="Tom")`.

Comment: Don’t over complicate things, if you’re testing Cat then use Cat and so on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree with [Joakim](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50839339/create-object-from-class-stored-in-variable/50839413#comment88682609_50839339): Probably best for `test_cat` to remain `test_cat` and explicitly test `Cat` (and so on).

But if you want to genericize it, you can with a `Class` instance and reflection, using [`getConstructor`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getConstructor-java.lang.Class...-) to get a relevant constructor, and then calling its [`newInstance`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Constructor.html#newInstance-java.lang.Object...-) method:

```
public void test(Class cls) {
    Constructor c = cls.getConstructor(new Object[] { String.class });
    Object instance = cls.newInstance("Tom");
    // ...
}
```

Calling it:

```
testerObject.test(Cat.class);
```

Obviously, add error handling and such.

You can also get methods from the class object, so you can (for instance) ensure that `getName` returns the name.